# How to arrange items in an array in all possible ways?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Items in an array can be arranged in ascending order using `sort()` method in JavaScript but how to arrange them in all possible ways and show them in our web page.

Comment: It would help if you were more specific in what you meant by "all possible ways".  Also, will the user initiate the action to sort them in a particular way?

Comment: By "all possible ways" I mean that like an array [a, b, c] can be arranged in 6 ways i.e. [a, b, c]  , [a, c, b] , [b, a, c ] , [b, c, a] , [c, a, b] and  [c, b, a].  The user will himself initiate the action by providing the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You describe permutations, one way to implement it:

```
function permutations(arr, r=[]) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    console.log(r)
  } else {
    const first = arr[0]
    for (let i = 0; i <= r.length; i++) {
      permutations(arr.slice(1), r.slice(0, i).concat([first]).concat(r.slice(i)))
    }
  }
}

permutations([1, 2, 3])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[ 3, 2, 1 ]
[ 2, 3, 1 ]
[ 2, 1, 3 ]
[ 3, 1, 2 ]
[ 1, 3, 2 ]
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```